# Defining template for TODO in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

When I create todo it adds only date by default:

```
// TODO: 2017-03-02
```

I would like to change this template for something else e.g.:

```
// TODO: 2017-03-02  Created by: @MyName
```

Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go into the Settings panel in the following section `Editor > Live Templates` there should be a live template for `todo` under `AndroidComments`. You'd have to tweak the existing template there or add an additional template with your changes.

If you're looking specifically for the template variable name for your logged in username that would be `${USER}`. If you need something different than that, you can specify your own custom template variable by following the Intellij documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/file-template-variables.html) under the section `Custom template variables`.

Here is an image of what I'm describing:

[image: Panel]